# How to Post/Get with body in Swift

Tags: node.js, swift, express

Im trying to connect to an api I made with node.js but it looks like there isn't a clear way to do it if there requires a body in the request. Im able to connect to it with postman on localhost because there i can set the params in the body but when i use the heroku url it throws an error. I read that apple made it so swift can no longer make requests with a body anymore. In another project i was able to successfully connect to an api made with python but instead of passing the data to the body it was passed as params. How can I change the api/swift code to accept the data as params in swift instead of the body?

Heres the function call in swift:

```
    func logoin() {
        
        let params: Parameters = [
            "email" : "test@email.com",
            "password" : "1234"
        ]

        AF.request("https://app_name.herokuapp.com/user/login", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"]).responseJSON  { response in

            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
            }

            else{

                let jsonData = try! JSON(data: response.data!)
                print("json data", response)
            }
        }
    }
```

Heres the api in node.js

```
const User = require('../models/user')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.get_user = (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.userId;
    User.findById(id)
        .exec()
        .then(doc => {
            console.log('From database', doc);

            if (doc) {
                res.status(200).json(doc);
            }
            else {

                res.status(404).json({ message: 'No valid entry found for user ID.' });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        });
};

exports.user_login = (req, res, next) => {
    User.find({ email: req.body.email }).exec().then(users => {
        if (users.length < 1) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Auth failed1'
            });
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, users[0].password, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Auth failed2'
                });
            }
            if (result) {
                const token = jwt.sign({
                    email: users[0].email,
                    userId: users[0]._id
                }, process.env.JWT_KEY)
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Auth successful',
                    token: token
                });
            }
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Auth failed3'
            });
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
};

exports.delete_user = (req, res, next) => {

    User.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.userId })
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'User deleted'
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
};

exports.update_user = (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.userId;
    const updateOps = {};
    for (const ops of req.body) {
        updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
    }
    User.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: updateOps })
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(200).json(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
};

exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {

    User.find({ email: req.body.email }).exec().then(user => {
        if (user.length >= 1) {
            return res.status(409).json({
                message: 'User already exists'
            });
        }
        else {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        error: err
                    });
                }
                else {
                    const user = new User({
                        firstname: req.body.firstname,
                        lastname: req.body.lastname,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        password: hash
                    });
                    user
                        .save()
                        .then(result => {
                            console.log(result)
                            res.status(201).json({
                                message: 'Successfully created user'
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                            res.status(500).json({
                                error: err
                            });
                        })
                }
            })
        }
    }).catch();
};
```

Comment: “Im able to connect to it with postman on localhost because there i can set the params in the body”. Fine. Now ask Postman to generate the Swift code for you, and you’re all set.

Comment: @matt thanks I didn't know postman could generate code like that. I tested it out and it looks like I'm hitting the 500 error in the catch. Iset up the config vars in heroku to include the mongodb url but im not too sure if its successfully connected so that might be it?  Apologies if this seems like an easy fix, web development isn't really my area.

Comment: @matt Got everything working. I used the code generated from postman to interface with the api. To fix the 500 error MongoDB was only allowing access to my ip so i had to allow outside access then redeploy my app in heroku.